# cvc-complex-type.2.4. Invalid content was found starting with element 'dw:transform-message'

Tags: javascript, java, mule, mule-studio

I develop a mule project in mule standalone 3.7.0 server.
I try to deploy in mule standalone 3.7.0 , i got a following error

"cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'dw:transform-message'"

But when i deployed with below schema

http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd

Still i couldn't get the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue using dataweave on mule standalone server. I got it resolved by copying all files from

```
AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.3.8.3.ee_6.2.1.201612161609\mule\plugins\mule-plugin-weave-3.8.3-dist\lib
```

this directory to

```
mule-standalone-3.8.1\lib\mule
```

this directory. Hope this is helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Dataweave is a Enterprise feature. But you should still be able to use it in Studio as long as you're using a EE runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple mule config files where you are using dataweave,  all the files should contain the  below header.

Make sure you also have dw in xmlns as below

```
<mule xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw"...........

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd"...."
```